# dpkg errors when running apt-get upgrade or installing new packages

Tags: apt, updates, dpkg, dkms

It all started after I tried to update AMD ROCm from version 3.5 to 4.0 to run tensorflow-rocm. The new version of ROCm is not working at all. While trying to install or running `apt-get upgrade`, Ubuntu (20.04 LTS) throws following errors.

```
Setting up qgis-providers (1:3.16.3+32focal) ...
    - 'VirtualXPath'    [XML Path Language - XPath]
    - 'VirtualXPath'    [XML Path Language - XPath]
    - 'VirtualXPath'    [XML Path Language - XPath]
free(): invalid pointer
Aborted (core dumped)
dpkg: error processing package qgis-providers (--configure):
installed qgis-providers package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 134 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qgis:
qgis depends on qgis-providers (= 1:3.16.3+32focal); however:
Package qgis-providers is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package qgis (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-qgis:
 python3-qgis depends on qgis-providers (= 1:3.16.3+32focal); however:
Package qgis-providers is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-qgis (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

Setting up rock-dkms (1:4.0-23) ...
Removing old amdgpu-4.0-23 DKMS files...

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 4.0-23
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new amdgpu-4.0-23 DKMS files...
Building for 5.8.0-38-generic 5.8.0-41-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.8.0-38-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/rock-dkms-firmware.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.8.0-38-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/4.0-23/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package rock-dkms (--configure):
 installed rock-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rocm-dkms:
rocm-dkms depends on rock-dkms; however:
Package rock-dkms is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package rocm-dkms (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
qgis-providers
qgis
python3-qgis
rock-dkms
rocm-dkms
```

Running `sudo dpkg --configure -a` also throws same errors.